# Populate jquery select drop down form with multiple lists

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, html-select

I've seen so many different posts that pertain to my situation, but I'm still learning server side and js code, so I just don't understand how to apply it to my problem yet.

I'm trying to build an order form to choose shirts/apparel to get screen printed. I don't have all the code in the form yet, as I'm already having problems, but here is the basic markup: (Keep in mind I plan on having a monetary value on the final selection to put towards a price estimate calculator with other sections in the form after I figure this part out.)

I don't know how to populate the third and fourth drop down, and I can already tell with my jquery markup, that `if($(this).val() == "100% Polyester/100% Cotton")` etc. will start to repeat itself.

HTML:

```
    `                <form>
                <select name="garment">
                    <option selected>Choose An Option</option>
                    <option>Short Sleeve T-Shirts</option>
                    <option>Hoodies/Sweatshirts</option>
                    <option>Long Sleeve T-Shirts</option>
                    <option>Tank Tops</option>
                    <option>Shorts &amp; Pants</option>
                    <option>Hats &amp; Accessories</option>
                </select>
                <select name="type">
                    <option selected disabled>Choose an Option</option>
                </select>
                <select name="style">
                    <option selected disabled>Choose an Option</option>
                </select>
                <select name="color">
                    <option selected disabled>Choose a Color</option>
                </select>
            </form>`
```

jquery:

```
     `$(document).ready(function() {

    $garment = $("select[name='garment']");
    $type = $("select[name='type']");
    $style = $("select[name='style']");

    $garment.change(function() {

    if($(this).val() == "Short Sleeve T-Shirts") {
        $("select[name='type'] option").remove();
        $("<option>100% Cotton</option>").appendTo($type);
        $("<option>Blended</option>").appendTo($type);
        $("<option>100% Polyester/Athletic</option>").appendTo($type);
    }
    if($(this).val() == "100% Cotton") {
        $("select[name='style'] option").remove();
        $("<option>Regular Fit</option>").appendTo($style);
        $("<option>Premium Slim/Fashion Fit</option>").appendTo($style);
        $("<option>Women's Cut</option>").appendTo($style);
    }
    if($(this).val() == "Blended") {
        $("select[name='style'] option").remove();
        $("<option>Regular Fit</option>").appendTo($style);
        $("<option>Premium Slim/Fashion Fit</option>").appendTo($style);
        $("<option>Women's Cut</option>").appendTo($style);
    }
    if($(this).val() == "100% Polyester/Athletic") {
        $("select[name='style'] option").remove();
        $("<option>Men's</option>").appendTo($style);
        $("<option>Women's</option>").appendTo($style);
    }

    });
    });`
```

Comment: Are you comfortable using ajax whether it be via jQuery or some other library?

Comment: You might check out this library. It seems that you are wanting to roll your own faceted-search implementation. This has got that all setup for you: http://eikes.github.io/facetedsearch/.

Comment: Haven't used it before, from what I've read on other/similar posts using ajax, I need to put the variable data in a database and pull from that?

Comment: There is no reason to use ajax for this problem.   In fact, it's probably a bad idea, especially if you are pulling the next dropdown's data from the server each time: The dropdown's will no longer be instantly responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ETLLOaRFojk3wKoCODVg?p=preview

Note that you only need to edit the linkedDropdowns array, and everything else will just work:

```
var linkedDropdowns = {
  "garment": {
    "Short Sleeve T-Shirts": ["100% Cotton", "Blended", "Polyester/Athletic"],
  },
  "type": {
    "100% Cotton": ["Regular Fit", "Premium Slim/Fashion Fit", "Women's Cut"],
    "Blended": ["Regular Fit", "Premium Slim/Fashion Fit", "Women's Cut"],
    "100% Polyester/Athletic": ["Men's", "Women's"]
  },
  "style": null 
};
$(function() {

    var dropdownNames = Object.keys(linkedDropdowns);

    dropdownNames.forEach( function(dropdownName) {

      var curIndex = dropdownNames.indexOf(dropdownName);
      if (curIndex === dropdownNames.length - 1)
        return;

      var curDropdown = $("select[name='" + dropdownName + "']");
      var nextDropdown = $("select[name='" + dropdownNames[curIndex+1] + "']");
      var nextOptions = linkedDropdowns[dropdownName];       

      curDropdown.change(function() {

          nextDropdown.find('option').remove().end();
          nextOptions[$(this).val()].forEach(function(curType) {
              $("<option>" + curType + "</option>").appendTo(nextDropdown);
          });
      });

    });
});
```

Comment: Dude... awesome. Thank you so much. One question though... where do I apply values to the final selection when I get to it? I need to have a value to apply to the next section of the app.

Comment: Hey, I edited the post to refactor the code even more, and now you only need to edit one array.  As for your question above, can you clarify?  Why can't you just read the value of the final dropdown using jquery?

Comment: Got a new question for ya, by using this method, how do I differentiate when the text is the same in different variables? i.e. When there's more than one drop down with "100% Cotton" `var linkedDropdowns = {
  "garment": {
    "Short Sleeve T-Shirts": ["Regular Fit", "Premium Slim/Fashion Fit", "Women's Cut", "100% Polyester/Athletic"],
  },
  "type": {
    "Regular Fit": ["100% Cotton", "Blends"],
    "Premium Slim/Fashion Fit": ["100% Cotton", "Blends", "V-Neck"],
    "Women's Cut": ["100% Cotton", "Blends"],
    "100% Polyester/Athletic": ["Men's", "Women's"],
  },
  "style": null
};`

Comment: Two options: One, you could use the entire sequence of dropdowns, rather than just the value of the last one, to uniquely identify the product.  I would probably opt for this route.  The other option is to specify the "value" field of each dropdown separately from its "text" (what we have now and what the user sees).  This would allow you to specify a product id or other unique identifer.  Supporting this would require some changes to the current code.

Comment: What would the markup look like for the first option? I do need to give the final choice a hidden price value that I can put into a function to calculate the price of an order. For instance, after someone picks a Hanes V-Neck, that needs to have a price of X to be multiplied by the text input in the size/quantity section, plus a few other inputs.

Comment: I think that's getting beyond the scope of the orginal question.  I'd want need to know more info about what you're doing, how the page is being submitted, what server side technology your using, exactly what the final goal is.  It may not *all* be relevant, but I'd post it as a new question with all that info, and all the relevant code.  Feel free to comment back here with the new link and I'll take a look

Answer (score -1):

If I'm understanding this correctly it looks like you need relational data. Rather than the list use a document.

e.g.

```
{
  "type":"Short Sleeve T-Shirts",
  "subtypes":[
    "100% Cotton",
    "100% Polyester/Athletic",
    "Blended"
  ],
  "colors":[
    "Blue",
    "Black",
    "Red"
  ]
}
```

or if the information is nested

```
{
  "type": "Short Sleeve T-Shirts",
  "subtypes":
  [
    {
      "name":"100% Cotton",
      "colors":[
        "Blue",
        "Black",
        "Red"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"100% Polyester/Athletic",
      "colors":[
        "Purple",
        "Green",
        "Orange"
      ]
    }
  ]

}
```

I don't know if you're limitations are using jquery but that's going to turn into a headache.

Have you considered using an MV* framework like [angular](http://angularjs.org)?

Comment: If you're going to downvote then comment with a reason. Otherwise I have no idea why you downvoted me.

Comment: I'm open to all suggestions. What are the benefits of angular.js? I've never used it before.

Comment: angularjs is an MV* framework that gives you bindings for your js data to your html. Angular is a prevalent solution, that I really prefer. 

Here's the basic concept video [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFTFsKmkQnQ)

In that video he first shows you jquery then changes to angular to show you how they compare. There are basic examples on their home page http://angularjs.org/

Comment: Appreciate it, I'll give it a look. Will post back if I get stuck with it.